# nothing happens after click on CardView (onClickListener)

Tags: android

I'm programming a hotel android application...
I used cardview and recycleview from [Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/) resources...

now I want put onClickListener on each item and I set onClickListener for thumbnails...

this is my HotelListAdapter:

```
    package ir.homa;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by SMQ on 7/3/2016.
 */
public class HotelListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HotelListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<HotelList> hotelList;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public HotelListAdapter(Context mContext, List<HotelList> hotelList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.hotelList = hotelList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)  {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hotel_list, parent, false);


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final HotelList hotel = hotelList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(hotel.getName());
        holder.count.setText(hotel.getNumOfRooms() + " اتاق");

        // loading hotel cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(hotel.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);

            }

        });
    }
/**
 * run intent filter when user clicked on each thumbnails!
 */
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.hotel_list_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }


    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {

        }

        @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "به علاقه مندی ها افزوده شد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_hotel_next:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "بزودی در دسترس قرار میگیرد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.card:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, MashhadHoma1.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "بزودی در دسترس قرار میگیرد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                default:
            }
            return false;
        }


    }
    private Context context;

    public HotelListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View view;
        public ClipData.Item currentItem;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.mipmap.mashhad_homa1:
                Intent openThree = new Intent(context,MashhadHoma1.class);
                context.startActivity(openThree);
                break;





        }
                }
            });
        }
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hotelList.size();
    }

}
```

This is my main activity:

```
   package ir.homa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomaActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private HotelListAdapter adapter;
    private List<HotelList> hotelList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homa);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            initCollapsingToolbar();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new HotelListAdapter(this, hotelList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepareHotels();

        try {
            Glide.with(this).load(R.color.bg_main).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.shoar));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

            private void prepareHotels() {
                int[] covers = new int[]{
                        R.mipmap.bandar_homa,
                        R.mipmap.mashhad_homa1,
                        R.mipmap.mashhad_homa,
                        R.mipmap.shiraz_homa,
                        R.mipmap.tehran_homa,
                };


                HotelList a = new HotelList(" هما - بندرعباس" , 13, covers[0]);
                hotelList.add(a);
                a = new HotelList("هما 1 - مشهد", 8, covers[1]);
                hotelList.add(a);

                a = new HotelList("هما 2 - مشهد", 8, covers[2]);
                hotelList.add(a);

                a = new HotelList("هتل هما - شیراز", 11, covers[3]);
                hotelList.add(a);

                a = new HotelList("هما - تهران", 11, covers[4]);
                hotelList.add(a);


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    /** onclick Listener for each item..*/


    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener

            /**
             * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
             */
            public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

                private int spanCount;
                private int spacing;
                private boolean includeEdge;

                public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
                    this.spanCount = spanCount;
                    this.spacing = spacing;
                    this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
                }
                @Override
                public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
                    int column = position % spanCount; // item column

                    if (includeEdge) {
                        outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                        outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                        if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                            outRect.top = spacing;
                        }
                        outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
                    } else {
                        outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                        outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                        if (position >= spanCount) {
                            outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homa, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomaActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomaActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I set a Switch/case for the onclickListener in HotelListAdapter:

```
public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View view;
        public ClipData.Item currentItem;
 public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.mipmap.mashhad_homa1:
                Intent openThree = new Intent(context,MashhadHoma1.class);
                context.startActivity(openThree);
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you `Log.i("something", "im in onclick");` just to verify if it enters that method at all. Also might wanna try clicking on various parts of the cardview, on the edges etc.

Comment: I set a Log when intent runs .

Comment: That sentence is not very helpful. What happens, we must isolate the error?

Comment: Sorry .. I write a log when intent runs and MashhadHoma1 coming .. but the log doesn't appear in logcat

Comment: Two things, 1 as Vucko said add a log command to your listener to make sure that it is acutally clicking. Second where is your context defined in that class? I don't see context being initialized anywhere.

Comment: I'm wondering why didn't you get a NPE !? `view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);` you're looking for `view` in itself while it's not initialized !? I believe it should be like this : `view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);` right?

Comment: Can you explain what is context exactly ?

Comment: @FarShaD How can I initialize it ?

Comment: @Mohammadreza The root view is `v` (the inflated argument passed to constructor), NOT `view`, So you're supposed to change your code to this : `view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);`

Comment: Thank U ... But It isn't working ! :(

Comment: I initialized context to mContext :  private Context context = mContext;

Comment: Can anyone help me ?!